# NSString! $T4 is not identical to [NSObject : AnyObject]

Tags: swift

I've been stuck on this error for almost two hours and can't figure out what is wrong. I've searched and it appears to be an issue with optionals?? I've tried messing around with the optionals to see if that would help but it didn't. I tried forced unwrapping to no avail.

the error occurs on: `self.videoURL = info(UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL)`

i've also defined videoURL as: `var videoURL: NSURL`

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
   self.videoURL = info(UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL)
   picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
   var sub = ShareViewController()
   sub.fileUrl = self.videoURL
   self.presentViewController(sub, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Did you want to write info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] instead of info(UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL)?

Comment: What is `info()` anyway?